# Is DataRowView an object of DataTable in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, datarow

I Bind the DataTable 'dt' to GridView like this.

```
 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

DataBind is successful.

In GridView Row DataBound I wrote like this:

```
DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
```

So my question is **'Is this DataRowView is an object of DataTable(dt) row'** ?
because if it is than I can edit rowView to insert the data in DataTable(dt), right ?

Comment: Yes it is, you can debug stop at this line and just rightClick on DataItem> QuickWatch in the right side of the table in the watch it will tell you the typeof the class it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datarowview is not an object of datatable but an object of dataview
datarowview is a view of datarow with status Default, Original, Current and Proposed.
so dataview wrap datatable and dataview wrap datarow
you can access datarow through Row property of datarowview

Comment: So any changes I do with rowView will reflect in DataTable????
Does it mean like this?

Comment: no any change on datatable can be filtered by status on dataview and datarowview